# Low power dual edge detector using too much power

Tags: transistors, flipflop, edge

I am creating a hobby circuit which transfer signal to edge triggered pulses. I created circuit like this:

[image]

But I have issue with power consumption. XOR gate need power which take 8mA which is really lot because it is powered from battery.

Does anybody know how to create circuit which does not require so much power? For my circuit is necessary create pulse on edge in meantime is turned off.

Comment: Raise R x1000 to reduce current and reduce C /1000 for same pulse width.

Comment: is IN swinging valid logic levels, rail to ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are operating this at a very high frequency 8ma is way too high for the HC technology.

The only way this could happen is if you are allowing the other IC inputs to float. Unused inputs should be tied to to Vcc or ground.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try connect unused inputs to ground (unused output too?). I am operating with very low frekvency (mHz).

Comment: Thanks, for first try it looks, it works...

Answer (score 0):

Is that a calculated current or a measured current?

These are the relevant specifications: Quiescent + Power dissipation due to switching. If you are switching infrequently, you should be close to quiescent.

This assumes that inputs are near the rail, if they are near the in-between switching region, the input current can be significantly higher. And it assumes that unused gates are pulled high or low so they won't oscillate or drift near the bad in-between region.

[image]

Comment: It is meassured current... I will try connect unused inputs to the ground. I look at the specification and i dont worry about consuption but I forgot the circuit on power and after 2 day battery was drained... 
I am switching in very low frekvency and not peridocally.